# Is there any way to store a SELECT result and output the resultset at the same time?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, stored-procedures, resultset

In the next sample procedure, can I output the row from the queried table as a procedure resultset, and at the same time store a single field or some fields in a variable (similarly as when I use SELECT INTO)? The only way I can imagine is repeating the query.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Panel_TerminalesForm`(IN idTerminal INT)
  BEGIN
    declare somefield INT:
    -- this select statement returns the found row as a resultset
    SELECT terminales.*
    FROM terminales
    WHERE id_terminal = idTerminal;
    -- but I also want to have here a table field inside the variable somefield
    -- do some manipulation with somefield...
END;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand you correctly, but it seems what you need is temp table.

Comment: I was looking for some way to tell MySQL "please do a SELECT INTO my vars but also oputput the resultset", but I'm afraid I can't, so the temptable is very likely to be a valid solution. If you post it as anser and the code is working I won't doubt to mark it as right

Comment: I post an answer, the result is the same of your query, but now you can do whatever you want in the temp table for out purposes without affecting the orig/physical table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you need to create a temporary table, then you can manipulate the temporary the way you want.

**MySQL:**

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE `Panel_TerminalesForm`(IN idTerminal INT)
        BEGIN
          declare somefield INT

          CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE SampleTempTable
          SELECT * INTO SampleTempTable FROM terminales WHERE id_terminal = idTerminal;

          -- output the resultset
          SELECT * FROM SampleTempTable   

          -- read the variables you want
          SELECT field INTO somefield FROM SampleTempTable   

          -- Drop the temp table
          DROP TEMPORARY TABLE SampleTempTable
    END;
```

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-temporary-table/

**SQL Server:**

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE `Panel_TerminalesForm`(IN idTerminal INT)
        BEGIN
          declare somefield INT

          SELECT terminales.* 
          INTO #tempSample FROM terminales
          WHERE id_terminal = idTerminal;

          SELECT * FROM #tempSample

          -- Drop the temp table
          DROP TABLE #tempSample
    END;
```

Note: Drop the temp table after using it to avoid errors.

Comment: Is the sharp syntax valid MySQL syntax for temp tables? I think it isn't

Comment: This looks more like SQL Server syntax.

Comment: I modified the answer for MySQL syntax of temp table.

Comment: Cool. I modified the MySQL part for really inserting into the temptable - you forgot it - and also reading a variable as I asked. I left the SQL Server part untouched since I don't want to screw it up. Nice solution!